# "Initializer for conditional binding...." after I fix, I get error "use of unresolved indentifier"

Tags: swift

I've created a function called prepareCamera. It checks for device type, media type, and camera position.

When I use the if/ let on my object availableDevices, I get the error "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type. After going through stack flow, I realized that my object is not an optional and if/let should only be used for optional type. I removed the if/ let, and I get the error, use of unresolved identifier.

My code is below. This is my first time using stackflow so bare with me haha. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class goliveViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer:CALayer!
    
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareCamera()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func prepareCamera () {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        
       if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera] , mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .front).devices {
            captureDevice = availableDevices.first
            beginSession()
        }
    }
    
    func beginSession () {
        
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
            self.previewLayer = previewLayer
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
            captureSession.startRunning()
            
            let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
                
                dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
                
                if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
                    captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
                }
            
                captureSession.commitConfiguration()
                        
        } 
    }
```

Comment: How about just removing the `if`, assuming you want `availableDevices` as a local variable?  (Well, also removing the braces that go with `if`.)